# Google App engine why Trace-agent isn't compatible with 0x module?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use `trace-agent` on Google App Engine along with 0x, but in my logs, it is showing

> ERROR:@google-cloud/trace-agent: TraceAgent#start: Tracing might not work as the following modules were loaded before the trace agent was initialized: [0x]

Can anyone please tell me how can I use both on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to our [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and open a feature request to have it fixed. Please provide all the details on the 0x module so we can figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I have already posted this question on Issue Tracker and they answered that they will ask with their product team. Also, about 0x module as I was starting my server.js file with 0x that's why I think it was getting loaded before trace agent, and that's why the error was there I guess.